# macOS Big Sur: How to use automator (or something else) to build a script for collecting data over time

Tags: excel, web-crawler, automator, macos-big-sur

I'm interested in a stock and I would like to build an automated script to collect data continuously from a webpage over a long period of time and with many data points, transfer that data to an excel file, and create an ongoing measure for the stock of interest. I have dipped my toe into Automator to do this but I would be receptive to learning of other methods to complete parts or all of this task.

I use

"Get Specified Finder Items"

to call the webpage where the stock info is, then

"Open Finder Items, Open with: Safari"

to open the webpage. Then I'm stuck.

I use

"Get text from Webpage"

to get plain text from webpage and I get

"Get Text from Webpage failed - 1 error, Frame load interrupted".

I've tried googling this error message but that brings up the error code in other contexts than how I encounter it and I can't find a troubleshooting guide to help with the error in Automator.

Can someone give me a reason why "Get Text from Webpage" results in a "frame load interrupted" error? There are no options to problem solve what to do to solve the problem; just the vague error.

Any additional help on how to build a program to mindlessly collect data over the day so I don't have to would be helpful. I don't see any options in automator to work with excel and I also don't know how to use "Get Text from Webpage" to specify what text to pull from the webpage. There is a lot of text on the page I'm using and I just want to pull the current stock price at the time of running.[image]

To clarify, I'm using a MacBook Pro with Big Sur so I need help with macOS for the problem we are working with. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I’ve never had much luck with Automator beyond the most basic stuff.  Usually you wind up using an AppleScript or Shell Script to perform custom stuff like that, so it is easier to just do it with those.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought..  perhaps you could make a shell script that would 1) use curl to pull the web data, 2) parse it, and 3) append the useful bits into a CSV file and achieve the same objective?  You could then put it in your crontab to pull the data at regular intervals.