# macOS Big Sur: AppleScript to open a webpage, read text, and write to an excel file

Tags: applescript

I started by using Automator to run a script that opens a web page, reads text, and writes to excel but I ran into an error and posted a question here:

[macOS Big Sur: How to use automator (or something else) to build a script for collecting data over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66436414/macos-big-sur-how-to-use-automator-or-something-else-to-build-a-script-for-co)

Now I found how to do it similarly with AppleScript and my code is as follows:

```
to goToWebPage(theWebPage)
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set URL of document 1 to theWebPage
end tell
end goToWebPage

goToWebPage("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/markets/")

to getInputByClass(theClass, num) -- defines a function with two inputs, theClass and num
tell application "Safari" --tells AS that we are going to use Safari    
    set input to do JavaScript "
document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in document 1 -        -   uses JavaScript to set the variable input to the information we want
end tell

return input --tells the function to return the value of the variable input
end getInputByClass

getInputByClass("r", 0)
```

The script opens the webpage but then returns the error "the variable input is not defined". Why is the script not defining input? Am I working with the wrong code from a boiler plate example I found online from years ago? I want to open the web page and select a text value that changes every minute or so and write it to an excel file. Any help is appreciated. I'm brand new to AppleScript and Automator.

########################
Edit:
Thanks for the feedback and the edits.

That is a really concise solution, thanks. But I don't know how long it will take me to understand what it does. Also it needs to write to an Excel workbook but that is a good way to make a lean version once I've had time to research the advanced functions it uses. Though I mostly like AppleScript so far over other languages because it uses more basic, English commands that can be figured out by reading the what the code is doing step by step so I can troubleshoot errors better than shorthand code that is hard to keep track of and impossible to read. But I may borrow this.

Here is an updated version of my work. I added some more stocks and I don't mind that it uses the computer applications like Safari and JavaScript though I wish I could avoid Automator and figure out how to get it to run in the background and compute while I veg out between excel data manipulation and code writing/learning. I'm looking into to saving it as an Applet or Application and using the idle handler. The short solution you provided may actually work with the idle handler. Mine doesn't because it has too many functions I think. I bought the computer and downloaded the programs to utilize them so it doesn't bother me if I sacrifice a fraction of my computing power to running things automatically and continuously. Here is my code. Sorry if it's not organized to your liking but I'm learning and the code makes sense to me to work it out and write it so I don't mind if is gibberish to someone else. This works except for the Excel month entry which I am working out on other forums. If anyone knows why excel returns an @ symbol smack dab in the middle of ("=TEXT(TODAY(), MMMM)") when AppleScript writes it to Excel I would appreciate another solution to my current progress.

```
--Boiler plate code to manipulate the HTML to let us pull the market price of the stock.--
--3 sets of modifiers for the 3 stocks--
#########################################################
to extractTextBitcoin(searchTextBitcoin, startTextBitcoin, endTextBitcoin)
    set tid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set startTextBitcoin to ">"
    set searchTextBitcoin to {"priceValue___11gHJ", 0 & searchTextBitcoin}
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startTextBitcoin
    set endItemsBitcoin to text item -1 of searchTextBitcoin
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to endTextBitcoin
    set beginningToEndBitcoin to text item 1 of endItemsBitcoin
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startTextBitcoin
    set endTextBitcoin to (text items 2 thru -1 of beginningToEndBitcoin) as record
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tid
end extractTextBitcoin

to extractTextLitecoin(searchTextLitecoin, startTextLitecoin, endTextLitecoin)
    set tid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set startTextLitecoin to ">"
    set searchTextLitecoin to {"priceValue___11gHJ", 0 & searchTextLitecoin}
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startTextLitecoin
    set endItemsLitecoin to text item -1 of searchTextLitecoin
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to endTextLitecoin
    set beginningToEndLitecoin to text item 1 of endItemsLitecoin
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startTextLitecoin
    set endTextLitecoin to (text items 2 thru -1 of beginningToEndLitecoin) as record
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tid
end extractTextLitecoin

to extractTextDogecoin(searchTextDogecoin, startTextDogecoin, endTextDogecoin)
    set tid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set startTextDogecoin to ">"
    set searchTextDogecoin to {"priceValue___11gHJ", 0 & searchTextDogecoin}
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startTextDogecoin
    set endItemsDogecoin to text item -2 of searchTextDogecoin
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to endTextDogecoin
    set beginningToEndDogecoin to text item 1 of endItemsDogecoin
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startTextDogecoin
    set endTextDogecoin to (text items 2 thru -1 of beginningToEndDogecoin) as record
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tid
end extractTextDogecoin
#########################################################
--A tell statement to open the webpage where the stocks are measured--
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    do shell script "open https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/"
end tell

delay 2

--A function that differentiates the data on the web page by class and number. It
--also uses JavaScript to write the data to a useable format.
to getInputByClassBitcoin(theClass, num)
    tell application "Safari"
        set BitcoinInput to do JavaScript "
        document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in document 1
    end tell
    return BitcoinInput
end getInputByClassBitcoin

--The function with the class and number criteria manually pulled from the web page--
getInputByClassBitcoin("priceValue___11gHJ", 0)

--Setting the instataneous stock price to a variable to input in Excel--
set BitcoinPrice to getInputByClassBitcoin("priceValue___11gHJ", 0)
on BitcoinFunction(BitcoinPrice)
    set BitcoinFunction to extractTextBitcoin(BitcoinPrice, "<div class=>", "</div>")
    return BitcoinFunction(BitcoinPrice)
end BitcoinFunction
#########################################################
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    do shell script "open https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/litecoin/"
end tell

delay 2

to getInputByClassLitecoin(theClass, num)
    tell application "Safari"
        set LitecoinInput to do JavaScript "
        document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in document 1
    end tell
    return LitecoinInput
end getInputByClassLitecoin

getInputByClassLitecoin("priceValue___11gHJ", 0)

set LitecoinPrice to getInputByClassLitecoin("priceValue___11gHJ", 0)
on LitecoinFuction(LitecoinPrice)
    set LitecoinFuction to extractTextLitecoin(LitecoinPrice, "<div class=>", "</div>")
    return LitecoinFuction(LitecoinPrice)
end LitecoinFuction
#########################################################
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    do shell script "open https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/dogecoin/"
end tell

delay 2

to getInputByClassDogecoin(theClass, num)
    tell application "Safari"
        set DogecoinInput to do JavaScript "
        document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in document 1
    end tell
    return DogecoinInput
end getInputByClassDogecoin

getInputByClassDogecoin("priceValue___11gHJ", 0)

set DogecoinPrice to getInputByClassDogecoin("priceValue___11gHJ", 0)
on DogecoinFuction(DogecoinPrice)
    set DogecoinFuction to extractTextDogecoin(DogecoinPrice, "<div class=>", "</div>")
    return DogecoinFuction(DogecoinPrice)
end DogecoinFuction
(*
#########################################################
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    do shell script "open https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/Ethereum/"
end tell

delay 2

to getInputByClassEthereum(theClass, num)
    tell application "Safari"
        set EthereumInput to do JavaScript "
        document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in document 1
    end tell
    return EthereumInput
end getInputByClassEthereum

getInputByClassEthereum("priceValue___11gHJ", 0)

set EthereumPrice to getInputByClassEthereum("priceValue___11gHJ", 0)
on EthereumFunction(EthereumPrice)
    set EthereumFunction to extractTextEthereum(EthereumPrice, "<div class=>", "</div>")
    return EthereumFunction(EthereumPrice)
end EthereumFunction
#########################################################
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    do shell script "open https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/Binance_coin/"
end tell

delay 2

to getInputByClassBinance_coin(theClass, num)
    tell application "Safari"
        set Binance_coinInput to do JavaScript "
        document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in document 1
    end tell
    return Binance_coinInput
end getInputByClassBinance_coin

getInputByClassBinance_coin("priceValue___11gHJ", 0)

set Binance_coinPrice to getInputByClassBinance_coin("priceValue___11gHJ", 0)
on Binance_coinFunction(Binance_coinPrice)
    set Binance_coinFunction to extractTextBinance_coin(Binance - coinPrice, "<div class=>", "</div>")
    return Binance_coinFunction(Binance_coinPrice)
end Binance_coinFunction
#########################################################
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    do shell script "open https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/Tether/"
end tell

delay 2

to getInputByClassTether(theClass, num)
    tell application "Safari"
        set TetherInput to do JavaScript "
        document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in document 1
    end tell
    return TetherInput
end getInputByClassTether

getInputByClassTether("priceValue___11gHJ", 0)

set TetherPrice to getInputByClassTether("priceValue___11gHJ", 0)
on TetherFunction(TetherPrice)
    set TetherFunction to extractTextTether(TetherPrice, "<div class=>", "</div>")
    return TetherFunction(TetherPrice)
end TetherFunction
#########################################################
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    do shell script "open https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/Polkadot/"
end tell

delay 2

to getInputByClassPolkadot(theClass, num)
    tell application "Safari"
        set PolkadotInput to do JavaScript "
        document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in document 1
    end tell
    return PolkadotInput
end getInputByClassPolkadot

getInputByClassPolkadot("priceValue___11gHJ", 0)

set PolkadotPrice to getInputByClassPolkadot("priceValue___11gHJ", 0)
on PolkadotFunction(PolkadotPrice)
    set PolkadotFunction to extractTextPolkadot(PolkadotPrice, "<div class=>", "</div>")
    return PolkadotFunction(PolkadotPrice)
end PolkadotFunction
#########################################################
*)
--Opens the compiled Excel workbook, negates user input, finds the next available--
--cell to input data, and fills the fields with Year, Month, Day, Time, and Price--
set {year:y, day:d} to (current date)
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    open "/Users/clusterflux/Desktop/人CRYPTO人_excel.xlsx"
    set display alerts to false
    activate object sheet "ㅇㅅㅇBITCOINㅇㅅㅇ"
    first row index of (get end (last cell of column 9) direction toward the top)
    set LastRowBitcoin to first row index of (get end (last cell of column 9) direction toward the top)
    --write date and time for each market reading to excel file
    set value of cell ("I" & LastRowBitcoin + 1) to y
    set value of cell ("J" & LastRowBitcoin + 1) to ("=TEXT(TODAY(), MMMM)")
    set value of cell ("K" & LastRowBitcoin + 1) to d
    set value of cell ("L" & LastRowBitcoin + 1) to (time string of (current date))
    set value of cell ("M" & LastRowBitcoin + 1) to BitcoinPrice
    activate object sheet "ㅇㅅㅇLITECOINㅇㅅㅇ"
    first row index of (get end (last cell of column 9) direction toward the top)
    set LastRowLitecoin to first row index of (get end (last cell of column 9) direction toward the top)
    set value of cell ("I" & LastRowLitecoin + 1) to y
    set value of cell ("J" & LastRowLitecoin + 1) to ("=TEXT(TODAY(), MMMM)")
    set value of cell ("K" & LastRowLitecoin + 1) to d
    set value of cell ("L" & LastRowLitecoin + 1) to (time string of (current date))
    set value of cell ("M" & LastRowLitecoin + 1) to LitecoinPrice
    activate object sheet "ㅇㅅㅇDOGECOINㅇㅅㅇ"
    first row index of (get end (last cell of column 9) direction toward the top)
    set LastRowDogecoin to first row index of (get end (last cell of column 9) direction toward the top)
    set value of cell ("I" & LastRowDogecoin + 1) to y
    set value of cell ("J" & LastRowDogecoin + 1) to ("=TEXT(TODAY(),  MMMM)")
    set value of cell ("K" & LastRowDogecoin + 1) to d
    set value of cell ("L" & LastRowDogecoin + 1) to (time string of (current date))
    set value of cell ("M" & LastRowDogecoin + 1) to DogecoinPrice
    set workbookName to ("人CRYPTO人_excel.xlsx") as string
    set destinationPath to (path to desktop as text) & workbookName
    save active workbook in destinationPath
    delay 2
    --close every workbook saving no--
    --tell application "Microsoft Excel"--
    --quit--
end tell

set closeURLs to {"https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/", "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/litecoin/", "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/dogecoin/"}

repeat with theURL in closeURLs
    tell application "Safari" to close (every tab of every window whose URL contains (contents of theURL))
end repeat
```

Comment: There is no class `"r"` in the mentioned URL

Comment: A couple of things, It easier to read _code_ that is organized. I'd suggest you put all your _handlers_ together, I always put them them at the bottom. -- `input` is typically used in a `run` _handler_, e.g. `on run {input, parameters}` and typically has a `return input` _statement_ just before the closing `end run` and `input` in this use case is a _list object_. -- In your `getInputByClass(theClass, num)` _handler_ I'd use a different variable then `input`, based on the _code_ you've shown.

Comment: I'd also `set var to missing value` as the first line within that _handler_ so if the `do JavaScript` fails at least `missing value` is returned to test against.  Set `var` to the _variable_ you choose. Also, I'd think you'd want _text_ returned not _html_, and if so then change `.innerHTML` to `.innerText` in the `do JavaScript`. -- `getInputByClass("r", 0)` will fail as there is no `r` _class_ on the page of the given **URL**, as mentioned by vadian. -- `getInputByClass("priceValue___11gHJ", 0)` worked fo me, with the other changes mentioned.  -- Testing was done in **Script Editor**.

Comment: Btw, the current way it runs is by creating an Automator alarm and copying it a bajillion times to run in 15 minute intervals throughout the day to collect a lot of data points to aggregate data to generate forecasting models for various crypto prices over a long period of reading the market.

Comment: Yeah, this was a very difficult thing for me to figure out. I took a lot of trial and error and just admitting that I don't know how to code yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AppleScript code I provided in this solution was taken from the in-depth solution I posted in your other topic

[Beginner AppleScript Writer having trouble with idle handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66471050/6844169)

Here is a different AppleScript approach which allows you to retrieve your Bitcoin Price values without the need for opening Safari, using JavaScript, Automator, or using text item delimiters.

```
property eGrepBitcoinPrice : "priceValue___11gHJ\">\\$\\d{2},\\d{3}.\\d{2}"
property currentBitcoinPrice : missing value

set currentBitcoinPrice to do shell script ¬
    "curl --no-keepalive 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/markets/' " & ¬
    "| grep -Eo " & quoted form of eGrepBitcoinPrice & " | cut -c 21-"
```

[image]