# Beginner AppleScript Writer having trouble with idle handler

Tags: excel, loops, applescript, modeling, macos-big-sur

I have been exploring coding recently and I really enjoy grinding a problem down. I am getting comfortable with AppleScript now and I think it is a good option for what I want to do in the future with coding. My gut tells me that Automator would be less efficient RAM wise and I don't like how it is sectioned off; to constraining and confusing. I like the sandbox feature of a scripting language. I built a pretty good script for a web crawler that opens an online stock portfolio and prunes the market price of cryptocurrencies. I plan on utilizing technological decision making labs to create a cryptocurrency forecasting workbook for my hopes and dreams to make money some day, if ever :[ I have day dreams of making a live excel file that builds plots with hourly fluctuations in the trading.

To make it a full fledged automated system I need some sort of way to loop the script or schedule it to run on a schedule to get lots of data points for the mathematical models I hope to formulate from the data. I have tried *really* hard to make the idle handler work but it just doesn't operate like the tutorials describe. It seems you can't use "on idle" with certain commands and I get an error every gosh darn time I use the thing. I found a help page that showed how to incorporate a "beep" function to make sure the idle loop is running and when I compile and save as an "always running App" it doesn't play the beep so I guess that's another problem I haven't figured out. I get the beep to work sometimes but with my final draft of my program now I can't get it to work. I have tried inserting it ever so carefully within tell statements because I have found it works with them sometimes. And I guess you can't have the idle handler span the entire script; it needs to be called in one command structures tree to work. But I still haven't had the App run the script from idle with all the work I've put in looking into this solution. Anybody that has the hush hush on the idle handler secrets can do their best to try to explain the inner workings of the script to me but I find that it takes me a long time to learn coding because it is a lot of very technical reading with precious few opportunities to forge your own learning. Coding is a lot of boiler plate rehashes and I assume I will be chipping away at writing code long into my grey hair days with what I've learned so far.

But if you could use this question to collect some reading material on how to take a moderately well written script to run in 30 minute increments in the background of a laptop that can handle most computing loads fairly well it would be most appreciated. I'm not against Automator; it's just hard in it's own right with all the things you have to know to get it to work. As I said, any info about the idle handler and how to get it to work would be helpful. Also, if it is possible to write code in AppleScript to generate plots in Microsoft Excel, I like making models for shirts and googles.

I guess I will share what I've worked on for the last chunk of a weeks worth of grinding the tutorials offered currently online for free. Any critiques or suggestions on how to make the script I've got so far better is greatly appreciated and I don't mind if you snatch something you like if I did a good jerb. This is a web crawling cryptocurrency stock analyzer currently. It follows 3 currencies and writes data to an excel file with year, month, day, and seconds to collect a mass of data for a stronger mathematical model. I studied technological forecasting techniques that apply seasonality to data so the forecasts are better than just using the trend line function in excel, though with the variability with cryptocurrency I wouldn't put much salt on a long term prediction of market prices. I just want to be watching for those oh so gut wrenching stock crashes for a chance to limp in to the game with what little money I can scrounge together for sustenance.

```
--Boiler plate code to manipulate the HTML to let us pull the market price of the stock.--
--3 sets of modifiers for the 3 stocks--
to extractTextBitcoin(searchTextBitcoin, startTextBitcoin, endTextBitcoin)
    set tid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set startTextBitcoin to ">"
    set searchTextBitcoin to {"priceValue___11gHJ", 0 & searchTextBitcoin}
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startTextBitcoin
    set endItemsBitcoin to text item -1 of searchTextBitcoin
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to endTextBitcoin
    set beginningToEndBitcoin to text item 1 of endItemsBitcoin
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startTextBitcoin
    set endTextBitcoin to (text items 2 thru -1 of beginningToEndBitcoin) as record
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tid
end extractTextBitcoin

to extractTextLitecoin(searchTextLitecoin, startTextLitecoin, endTextLitecoin)
    set tid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set startTextLitecoin to ">"
    set searchTextLitecoin to {"priceValue___11gHJ", 0 & searchTextLitecoin}
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startTextLitecoin
    set endItemsLitecoin to text item -1 of searchTextLitecoin
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to endTextLitecoin
    set beginningToEndLitecoin to text item 1 of endItemsLitecoin
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startTextLitecoin
    set endTextLitecoin to (text items 2 thru -1 of beginningToEndLitecoin) as record
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tid
end extractTextLitecoin

to extractTextDogecoin(searchTextDogecoin, startTextDogecoin, endTextDogeecoin)
    set tid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set startTextDogecoin to ">"
    set searchTextDogecoin to {"priceValue___11gHJ", 0 & searchTextDogecoin}
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startTextDogecoin
    set endItemsDogecoin to text item -2 of searchTextDogecoin
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to endTextDogeecoin
    set beginningToEndDogecoin to text item 1 of endItemsDogecoin
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startTextDogecoin
    set endTextDogeecoin to (text items 2 thru -1 of beginningToEndDogecoin) as record
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tid
end extractTextDogecoin

--A tell statement to open the webpage where the stocks are measured--
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    do shell script "open https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/"
end tell

delay 2

--A function that differentiates the data on the web page by class and number. It
--also uses JavaScript to write the data to a useable format.
to getInputByClassBitcoin(theClass, num)
    tell application "Safari"
        set input to do JavaScript "
        document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in document 1
    end tell
    return input
end getInputByClassBitcoin

--The function with the class and number criteria manually pulled from the web page--
getInputByClassBitcoin("priceValue___11gHJ", 0)

--Setting the instataneous stock price to a variable to input in Excel--
set BitcoinPrice to getInputByClassBitcoin("priceValue___11gHJ", 0)
on FinalFuction(BitcoinPrice)
    set FinalFuction to extractTextBitcoin(BitcoinPrice, "<div class=>", "</div>")
    return FinalFuction(BitcoinPrice)
end FinalFuction

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    do shell script "open https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/litecoin/"
end tell

delay 2

to getInputByClassLitecoin(theClass, num)
    tell application "Safari"
        set token to do JavaScript "
        document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in document 1
    end tell
    return token
end getInputByClassLitecoin

getInputByClassLitecoin("priceValue___11gHJ", 0)

set LitecoinPrice to getInputByClassLitecoin("priceValue___11gHJ", 0)
on ReturnFuction(LitecoinPrice)
    set ReturnFuction to extractTextLitecoin(LitecoinPrice, "<div class=>", "</div>")
    return ReturnFuction(LitecoinPrice)
end ReturnFuction

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    do shell script "open https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/dogecoin/"
end tell

delay 2

to getInputByClassDogecoin(theClass, num)
    tell application "Safari"
        set blast to do JavaScript "
        document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in document 1
    end tell
    return blast
end getInputByClassDogecoin

getInputByClassDogecoin("priceValue___11gHJ", 0)

set DogecoinPrice to getInputByClassDogecoin("priceValue___11gHJ", 0)
on EndFuction(DogecoinPrice)
    set EndFuction to extractTextDogecoin(DogecoinPrice, "<div class=>", "</div>")
    return EndFuction(DogecoinPrice)
end EndFuction

--Opens the compiled Excel workbook, negates user input, finds the next available--
--cell to input data, and fills the fields with Year, Month, Day, Time, and Price--
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    open "/Users/clusterflux/Desktop/ㅇㅅㅇBITCOINㅇㅅㅇ.xlsx"
    set display alerts to false
    delete active sheet
    first row index of (get end (last cell of column 9) direction toward the top)
    set LastRow to first row index of (get end (last cell of column 9) direction toward the top)
    --write date and time for each market reading to excel file
    set value of cell ("I" & LastRow + 1) to "=YEAR(TODAY())"
    set value of cell ("J" & LastRow + 1) to "=MONTH(TODAY())"
    set value of cell ("K" & LastRow + 1) to "=DAY(TODAY())"
    set value of cell ("L" & LastRow + 1) to (time string of (current date))
    set value of cell ("M" & LastRow + 1) to BitcoinPrice
    set workbookName to ("ㅇㅅㅇBITCOINㅇㅅㅇ.xlsx") as string
    set destinationPath to (path to desktop as text) & workbookName
    save active workbook in destinationPath
end tell

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    open "/Users/clusterflux/Desktop/ㅇㅅㅇLITECOINㅇㅅㅇ.xlsx"
    set display alerts to false
    delete active sheet
    first row index of (get end (last cell of column 5) direction toward the top)
    set LastRow to first row index of (get end (last cell of column 5) direction toward the top)
    set value of cell ("C" & LastRow + 1) to "=YEAR(TODAY())"
    set value of cell ("D" & LastRow + 1) to "=MONTH(TODAY())"
    set value of cell ("E" & LastRow + 1) to "=DAY(TODAY())"
    set value of cell ("F" & LastRow + 1) to (time string of (current date))
    set value of cell ("G" & LastRow + 1) to LitecoinPrice
    set workbookName to ("ㅇㅅㅇLITECOINㅇㅅㅇ.xlsx") as string
    set destinationPath to (path to desktop as text) & workbookName
    save active workbook in destinationPath
end tell
on idle
    return 3
    beep
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        open "/Users/clusterflux/Desktop/ㅇㅅㅇDOGECOINㅇㅅㅇ.xlsx"
        set display alerts to false
        delete active sheet
        first row index of (get end (last cell of column 5) direction toward the top)
        set LastRow to first row index of (get end (last cell of column 5) direction toward the top)
        set value of cell ("C" & LastRow + 1) to "=YEAR(TODAY())"
        set value of cell ("D" & LastRow + 1) to "=MONTH(TODAY())"
        set value of cell ("E" & LastRow + 1) to "=DAY(TODAY())"
        set value of cell ("F" & LastRow + 1) to (time string of (current date))
        set value of cell ("G" & LastRow + 1) to DogecoinPrice
        set workbookName to ("ㅇㅅㅇDOGECOINㅇㅅㅇ.xlsx") as string
set destinationPath to (path to desktop as text) & workbookName
        save active workbook in destinationPath
    end tell
end idle
```

Sorry in advance if my formatting isn't up to snuff. I'm still a newbie.

Comment: I fixed the formatting however the walls of text you have will probably stop some from even reading this.  I know I'm not going to!

Comment: Looking at it again, your code is a bit confusing since a lot is duplicated and/or unused.  The main issue seems to be that the `idle` handler isn’t used at all (the `return` statement exits the handler).  There also really isn't much of a looping structure to use in an `idle` handler other than putting the whole script in it, but the script needs to be refactored since handlers are intermixed with the main run statements.

Comment: yeah, I don't really understand how to code by many rules yet. I like to just **** up until I figure something out. Not really writing it for other people to enjoy reading, lord knows I don't like reading through anybody else's attempts at making this stuff easy to decipher.

Comment: I think all the code is used in some way, not sure what you mean by duplicating. I had to duplicate and modify to get it to do what I wanted the way I could figure out to brute force the AppleScript program.

Comment: The duplication is with the repeating of code that only differ by a couple of words for the web pages and workbooks - these can easily be replaced by handlers that take a parameter for the different page or workbook (that is what handlers are for).  The `[final | return | end]Function` handlers are not used at all, which is probably for the better - they won’t run at all because you are redefining the handler symbol/variable (and if that is fixed they will recurse until the stack overflows).

Comment: Yeah handlers are confusing to me so far. I'm bad with functions. But I will try to learn more as I go. Just figuring it out without any experience.

Comment: It helps to post and get a checkpoint to circle back to and find related stuff to absorb over time. I'm slow with code learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a different AppleScript approach which allows you to retrieve your Bitcoin Price values without the need for opening Safari, using JavaScript, Automator, or using text item delimiters. This may not be exactly what you’re looking for but at least it offers a different approach using much less code. Hopefully you can adapt some of it to your needs.

The first 3 properties in the code define the `regular expressions` which will be used in the `do shell script` commands, which will extract the dollar values from the HTML source code.

For example, to quickly explain what `property eGrepBitcoinPrice : "priceValue___11gHJ\”>\\$\\d{2},\\d{3}.\\d{2}”` means… we will be searching for text inside the HTML which contains “priceValue___11gHJ” followed by a “>” followed by “$” followed by any 2 digits followed by a “,” followed by any 3 digits followed by a “.” and followed by any 2 digits

Because I do not have Microsoft Excel, I could not include those commands in the code. However, I did create a quick logging function which writes the prices to a plain text file on your Desktop “Price Log.txt”. This functionality can easily be disabled or removed. The log commands are all wrapped up within a `script object` called `script logCommands` which can be removed or commented out along with any other lines in the code which contain `my logCommands's`.

Here is a snapshot of the log file

[image]

Save this following AppleScript code in Script Editor.app as a “stay open” application.  Being that it is a “stay open” application, when the applet is launched outside of Script Editor.app, only what is within the explicit `on run` handler will run only one time.  The rest of the magic happens within the `on idle` handler… and everything within this handler will run every 300 seconds. If you want the commands to repeat every 30 minutes, just set the `return` value to 1800.

```
property eGrepBitcoinPrice : "priceValue___11gHJ\">\\$\\d{2},\\d{3}.\\d{2}"
property eGrepLitecoinPrice : "priceValue___11gHJ\">\\$\\d{3}.\\d{2}"
property eGrepDogecoinPrice : "priceValue___11gHJ\">\\$\\d{1}.\\d{5}"
property currentBitcoinPrice : missing value
property currentLitecoinPrice : missing value
property currentDogecoinPrice : missing value
property logToTextFile : missing value

on run --   Executed Only Once.. When This Script Applet Is Launched
    activate
    set logToTextFile to (display dialog ¬
        "Enable Quick Log Mode?" buttons {"No", "Yes"} ¬
        default button 2 with title "Log Mode")
    if button returned of logToTextFile = "Yes" then
        my logCommands's beginLog()
        getPrices()
    else
        getPrices()
        return {currentBitcoinPrice, currentDogecoinPrice, currentLitecoinPrice}
    end if
end run

on idle
    getPrices()
    if button returned of logToTextFile = "Yes" then my logCommands's writeToLog()
    
    (* within this idle handler is where you will place
    The bulk of your additional code. All of your Excel
    Code Goes Here*)
    
    return 300 -- In Seconds, How Often To Run Code In This Idle Handler
end idle

---------- PLACE ALL ADDITIONAL HANDLERS BENEATH THIS LINE ----------

on getPrices()
    set currentBitcoinPrice to do shell script ¬
        "curl --no-keepalive 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/markets/' " & ¬
        "| grep -Eo " & quoted form of eGrepBitcoinPrice & " | cut -c 21-"
    set currentLitecoinPrice to do shell script ¬
        "curl --no-keepalive 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/litecoin/' " & ¬
        "| grep -Eo " & quoted form of eGrepLitecoinPrice & " | cut -c 21-"
    set currentDogecoinPrice to do shell script ¬
        "curl --no-keepalive 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/dogecoin/' " & ¬
        "| grep -Eo " & quoted form of eGrepDogecoinPrice & " | cut -c 21-"
end getPrices

on quit --  Executed Only When The Script Quits
    if button returned of logToTextFile = "Yes" then my logCommands's endLog()
    continue quit -- Allows The Script To Quit
end quit

script logCommands
    property pathToPriceLog : POSIX path of (path to desktop as text) & "Price Log.txt"
    on beginLog()
        set startTime to ("Start Time... " & (current date) as text) & ¬
            " Price Scanning At 5 Minute Intervals"
        do shell script "echo " & startTime & " >> " & ¬
            quoted form of pathToPriceLog
    end beginLog
    on writeToLog()
        do shell script "echo " & "Bitcoin:" & quoted form of currentBitcoinPrice & ¬
            "   Dogecoin:" & quoted form of currentDogecoinPrice & ¬
            "  Litecoin:" & quoted form of currentLitecoinPrice & ¬
            "     " & quoted form of (time string of (current date)) & ¬
            " >> " & quoted form of pathToPriceLog
    end writeToLog
    on endLog()
        set endTime to quoted form of "End Time... " & (current date) as text
        do shell script "echo " & endTime & " >> " & ¬
            quoted form of pathToPriceLog
        do shell script "echo " & " " & " >> " & ¬
            quoted form of pathToPriceLog
    end endLog
end script
```

Unfortunately “stay open” applications and scripts when launched from within Script Editor.app, will not execute what is within the `idle handler`.  So the “stay open” application needs to be launched from within Finder, like any other applications, to observe the results of the `idle` commands as they are happening. This was the main reason I included a logging to file function… so I could observe the results of the `idle` commands in real time.

Contrary to what a lot of people think, most “stay open” applications use very little system resources.

[image]

---

**UPDATED APPLESCRIPT CODE DUE TO CHANGED URL SOURCE CODE**

```
property eGrepBitcoinPrice : "priceValue\\ \">\\$\\d{2},\\d{3}.\\d{2}"
property eGrepLitecoinPrice : "priceValue\\ \">\\$\\d{3}.\\d{2}"
property eGrepDogecoinPrice : "priceValue\\ \">\\$\\d{1}.\\d{4}"
property currentBitcoinPrice : missing value
property currentLitecoinPrice : missing value
property currentDogecoinPrice : missing value
property logToTextFile : missing value

on run --   Executed Only Once.. When This Script Applet Is Launched
    activate
    set logToTextFile to (display dialog ¬
        "Enable Quick Log Mode?" buttons {"No", "Yes"} ¬
        default button 2 with title "Log Mode")
    if button returned of logToTextFile = "Yes" then
        my logCommands's beginLog()
        getPrices()
    else
        getPrices()
        return {currentBitcoinPrice, currentDogecoinPrice, currentLitecoinPrice}
    end if
end run

on idle
    getPrices()
    try
        if button returned of logToTextFile = "Yes" then my logCommands's writeToLog()
    on error errMsg number errNum
        my logCommands's writeToLog()
    end try
    
    (* within this idle handler is where you will place
    The bulk of your additional code. All of your Excel
    Code Goes Here*)
    
    return 300 -- In Seconds, How Often To Run Code In This Idle Handler
end idle

---------- PLACE ALL ADDITIONAL HANDLERS BENEATH THIS LINE ----------

on getPrices()
    set currentBitcoinPrice to do shell script ¬
        "curl --no-keepalive 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/markets/' " & ¬
        "| grep -Eo " & quoted form of eGrepBitcoinPrice & " | cut -c 14-"
    set currentLitecoinPrice to do shell script ¬
        "curl --no-keepalive 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/litecoin/' " & ¬
        "| grep -Eo " & quoted form of eGrepLitecoinPrice & " | cut -c 14-"
    set currentDogecoinPrice to do shell script ¬
        "curl --no-keepalive 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/dogecoin/' " & ¬
        "| grep -Eo " & quoted form of eGrepDogecoinPrice & " | cut -c 14-"
end getPrices

on quit --  Executed Only When The Script Quits
    if button returned of logToTextFile = "Yes" then my logCommands's endLog()
    continue quit -- Allows The Script To Quit
end quit

script logCommands
    property pathToPriceLog : POSIX path of (path to desktop as text) & "Price Log.txt"
    on beginLog()
        set startTime to ("Start Time... " & (current date) as text) & ¬
            " Price Scanning At 5 Minute Intervals"
        do shell script "echo " & startTime & " >> " & ¬
            quoted form of pathToPriceLog
    end beginLog
    on writeToLog()
        do shell script "echo " & "Bitcoin:" & quoted form of currentBitcoinPrice & ¬
            "   Dogecoin:" & quoted form of currentDogecoinPrice & ¬
            "  Litecoin:" & quoted form of currentLitecoinPrice & ¬
            "     " & quoted form of (time string of (current date)) & ¬
            " >> " & quoted form of pathToPriceLog
    end writeToLog
    on endLog()
        set endTime to quoted form of "End Time... " & (current date) as text
        do shell script "echo " & endTime & " >> " & ¬
            quoted form of pathToPriceLog
        do shell script "echo " & " " & " >> " & ¬
            quoted form of pathToPriceLog
    end endLog
end script
```

Comment: This is really helpful for future progress in my code learning. Thanks for explaining things out better than most and not being rude. We all have to start somewhere. Right now the code I have worked on works for what I want even if it does it in a weird way so I am taking a break from breaking new ground but I will study this. Thank you, seriously.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on this hobby. I've started back on the project and run into a problem with the code you wrote that used to work. Now the website has changed the HTML code to simply "priceValue " and the code you wrote doesn't fetch the values anymore. The website is coinmarketcap.com. I've tried modifying the HTML code in the applescript application but it doesn't work. Any suggestions on how to get it to work again and print out values? @wch1zpink

Comment: @macandcheese-spaghetti  I added an update to the post which should solve your problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. You are the cornerstone of the project as far as we are concerned. I werked out the code in Excel and posted it to Github. But this poster was the real coder that figured out the jumps from the host site. I'm still not good at problem solving code blocks on my own.

Comment: It werks on you log.txt file but not excel. Yours is a pretty good program though. A lot less light weight and you can watch it change live without opening the file on Mac.